# Как разместить простое ASP.NET MVC приложение на IIS сервере?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Второй день не могу найти ничего путного по данному вопросу. Делаю так:

1. Захожу в "Диспетчер служб IIS".
2. ПКМ по "сайты" -> "Добавить новый сайт".
3. Ввожу имя, указываю физический путь "C:\inetpub\wwwroot", IP своего ПК, имя узла как в названии.
4. После импортирую опубликованную версию проекта на сайт.

Когда пытаюсь зайти, пишет: "Не удается получить доступ к сайту. Не удалось найти IP-адрес сервера...ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED".

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не так делаю? Или посоветуйте годное видео с решением.

P.S. Пытаюсь запустить на локальном компьютере.

Comment: По IP зайти получается?

Comment: @free_ze Пока ждал ответа, импортировал на сайт опубликованную версию проекта и сделал чтобы можно было заходить по имени. Но теперь другая проблема, вместо отображения сайта я вижу список файлов в папке с сайтом. Как быть?

Comment: А в приложении в корне есть файл Global.asax и web.config?